# recursive procedure height of tree

Tags: mips

I'm trying to write a function that calculates the height of a tree using this algorithm:

```
height(root)
    if root == nil then return 0
    h1 = height(root.left)
    h2 = height(root.right)
    answer = max(h1,h2) +1
    return answer
```

first I call the function passing the root, the  the base case, if the tree is null the height is zero, else call the recursion on the left son of the root and store the value, then call the recursion on the right son of the root and store the value, then the height is simply the maximum value between the left and right son plus the root.

I've implemented this in mars but I received: Error in /Users/mips1.asm line 47: Runtime exception at 0x0040004c: store address not aligned on word boundary 0x00000007

```
.data
tree: .word a
a: .word 3, y, c
y: .word 21, d, e 
c: .word 4, 0, 0
d: .word 5, f, g 
e: .word -3, 0, h 
f: .word 6, 0, 0 
g: .word 9, i, 0 
h: .word 18, 0, w 
i: .word 22, 0, 0 
w: .word 1, 0, 0 
answer: .word 0

.text
.globl main

main:

    la $v0, a
    lw $a0, 0($v0)
    jal height
    sw $v0, answer


    #print
    li $v0,1
    lw $a0, answer
    syscall

    #end
    li $v0, 10
    syscall

#________________________________________
#height
.globl height
height:
    addi $sp, $sp, -12
    sw $ra, 0($sp)
    sw $s0, 4($sp)

    #base case
    li $v0, 0
    beq $a0, 0, leaf

    move $s0, $a0

    sw $a0, 4($a0) #x.left
    jal height

    sw $a0, 8($a0) #x.right
    jal height

    #answer = max(heigtLeft, heigtRight)+1


leaf:
       lw $ra, 0($sp)
       lw $s0, 4($sp)
       addi $sp, $sp, 8
       jr $ra
```

Comment: Well, you load the first value at `a` (i.e. 3) into `$a0`, and then try to store something to `4($a0)` (i.e. address 7), which obviously is wrong. MARS has plenty of debugging features that lets you set breakpoints, single-step through code, view register and memory contents, etc. Make use of them.

Comment: so what I have to do? sorry but this is the first time I use mips I'm trying to help

Comment: You need to think through what it is that you want to achieve, step by step. What was your intention with that `sw`? What did you want it to store, and to where? Once you've determined that, think about how you get the appropriate values into the registers at that point, and so on.